# Load local jqGrid data through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am using the following code to load data from server side through AJAX and then use local data for displaying it in the jqGrid. I can't use `loadonce` as it will not support pagination. Please find my code below :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard/grid',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {_token: $('#csrf_token').val(),from:from, to:to},
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            gridData = data;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

    var data = $grid = $("#dash_grid"), gridData;

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: data,
        search:true,
        jsonReader: {cell:""},
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        caption: "Multiple search with local data",
        colNames:['Date','Impressions', 'Revenue'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'date',index:'date', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
            {name:'impressions',index:'impressions', editable: true, width:90},
            {name:'revenue',index:'revenue', editable: true, width:100},
        ]
    });
```

It is not showing any error but not loading any data. If I copy the AJAX response and use it in the place where I am setting the data, it is working. How can I make this working ?

Comment: Ajax work **asynchronously**. The callback of `.done` will be executed only after receiving the response from the server (from 'dashboard/grid'). Even if you would fix the line `var data = $grid = $("#dash_grid"), gridData;` to `var data = gridData;` if will be work incorrectly because `gridData` would be undefined at the time of `var data = gridData;` and at the time of creating the grid.

Comment: @Oleg so how can I fix this ?  giving async:false will work ?

Comment: You can create jqGrid inside of `.done(function(data) {/*here*/})`. Another way you can just use `datatype: "json", mtype: "POST", url: "dashboard/grid", postData: { _token: function () { return $('#csrf_token').val(); }, from: from, to:to }, loadonce: true`. In the case jqGrid will makes the same call for you and will fill the data. It's important just to know exactly the format (an example) of returned data. It could be that one need use some additional `jsonReader` parameters of `jsonmap` property in `colModel`. It's important to know whether the `$.ajax` call be made once or multiple times

Comment: loadone will not have the pagination property right ?I have data in the same format that of here : http://jsfiddle.net/hekai/QEzhr/1/ and I am calling ajax only once to load the data.

Comment: I can't see any problems with paging in the demo. How many **total rows** needed be return from the server at once? Which version and which fork of jqGrid you use?